# CSS Menu Design - Contend under Menu

Tags: html, css, menu, header

I am still new to this and having some issues. I have a problem with my menu and body. What i want is have an Image with content right beneath the menu. The problem in my case is, that the section class in the body goes under the content from the nav tag, which makes the h1 Text disappear under the Menu as well.

When i did my first project, i did not have this issue. I mostly copied the code from my first project - i do not see even after research what exactly is wrong with the code. I also can not change the color of the Links - everything else can be changed. Am i missing something?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<title>Portfolio Page</title>
</head>

<body>

<header>
        <class class="logo">Logo Name</class>
    <nav>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
        <a href="#">Contacts</a>

    </nav>
</header>

<section class="intro">
    <h1>Hello, this is the Page Intro!</h1>
    <p>This is some smaller Text!</p>
</section>

<section class="information">
    <p>Here will be some Infos</p>
</section>

</body>

<footer>
<p>Copyright @2020</p>
</footer>

</html>
```

And here is the CSS

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

html, body {
 height: 100%;
}

body{ 
 font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
}

header{
 background-color: #222;
 width: 100%;
 height: 8vh;
 display: flex;
 position: fixed;
}

nav{
 flex: 1;
 align-self: center;
}

nav a{
 color: rgb(197, 197, 14);
 text-decoration: none;
 list-style: none;
 color: black;
 margin-left: 5vh;
 font-weight: 600;
 font-size: 24px;
 letter-spacing: 3px;
}


.logo{
 color: rgb(197, 197, 14);
 flex:1;
 align-self: center;
 margin-left: 5vh;
 letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.intro{
 text-align: center;
 background-image: url(img/flat2.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center; 
 width: 100%;
 height: 60vh;

}

h1{
 padding-top: 25px;
 }

.information{
  background-color: #222;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 60vh;
  color: rgb(197, 197, 14);
}


footer{
 background-color: whitesmoke;
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 4vh;

 }

footer p{
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 12px;
 margin-top: 8px;
}
```

Also, the footer does not stick to the bottom and just floats in the middle of the page. Which seems weird, i did not have this problem before.

Thanks for the help anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add some top padding in your `intro` class
2. Removed the `color: black;` in your `nav a`
3. Footer element should be inside your body tag

https://jsfiddle.net/oLu2tn58/

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
}

header {
  background-color: #222;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8vh;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
}

nav {
  flex: 1;
  align-self: center;
}

nav a {
  color: rgb(197, 197, 14);
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 5vh;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.logo {
  color: rgb(197, 197, 14);
  flex: 1;
  align-self: center;
  margin-left: 5vh;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.intro {
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url(img/flat2.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60vh;
  padding-top: 8vh;
}

h1 {
  padding-top: 25px;
}

.information {
  background-color: #222;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 60vh;
  color: rgb(197, 197, 14);
}

footer {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  text-align: center;
  position: static;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4vh;
}

footer p {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>Portfolio Page</title>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <class class="logo">Logo Name</class>
    <nav>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
      <a href="#">Contacts</a>

    </nav>
  </header>

  <section class="intro">
    <h1>Hello, this is the Page Intro!</h1>
    <p>This is some smaller Text!</p>
  </section>

  <section class="information">
    <p>Here will be some Infos</p>
  </section>

  <footer>
    <p>Copyright @2020</p>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Worked. The color:black; was probably a rookie mistake then. 

But when i put my footer Tags in the Body tag, right between the closing main and closing body. It still does not work. In your jsfiddle.net example it works.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I also modified the css of your footer

Answer (score 0):

1st) for link colors you have 2 colors, just delete color: black; 2) position: fixed in header is similar to position: absolute; as in that it doesnt move content around it, rather over, so you should just add padding-top or margin-top to header, to just push it away from top.

Comment: See in .nav a{ color: rgb(197, 197, 14); }

Comment: you did not add class to nav, so you should just use nav a {color: rgb(197, 197, 14);}  wiuthout the dot. or just add class to all nav links, example : <nav>
        <a class='nav-link' href="#">Home</a> and then target .nav-link in css, pardon didnt copy whole css :(

Comment: you have 2 colors in nav a, this is css (Cascading style sheets) bottom color is valid

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the title problem can be solved by adding some additional padding.

```
h1 {
    padding-top: 150px;
}
```

Links color didn't kick in because it was defined as black after. So it got overwritten. In the following block, delete `color: black` and the color defined earlier will apply.

```
nav a{
 color: rgb(197, 197, 14);
 text-decoration: none;
 list-style: none;
 color: black;
 margin-left: 5vh;
 font-weight: 600;
 font-size: 24px;
 letter-spacing: 3px;
}
```